# FS Bucket - Clever Cloud, how to properly use it?

Tags: php, bucket, clever-cloud

We're trying to implementate a bucket system in our apps.

[image]

[FS-Bucket](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/deploy/addon/fs-bucket/) is an alternative provided also by Clever Cloud, that is our PaaS/IaaS provider.

The issue might be in the [documentation](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/deploy/addon/fs-bucket/#), that is not really good telling or extensive about the tool at all.

How can we interact with our bucket properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Using the `CC_FS_BUCKET` mentioned in [documentation](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/deploy/addon/fs-bucket/#)**
2. Using FTP (boring and slow, but it works).

Once you adquire the FS Bucket, it will provide you a HOST and other credentials.

The idea is to set the environment variable in the one app the we need to use the bucket.

something like this:

```
CC_FS_BUCKET=/my-bucket-folder:bucket-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-fsbucket.services.clever-cloud.com
```

That will mount a folder to access directly from our app (** **In the execution environmet** **)

[image]

once this is done and deployed, we can try like this SIMPLE example:

```php
<?php

// this script is located one folder under root, check if your case is similar and modificate the realpath(...) parameter
define("ROOT_DIR_APP", realpath(__DIR__ ."/../"));

try {

    $file = $_GET['file'];

    if (empty($file) || !isset($file)) {
        echo "No file specified or included";
        exit;
    }

    // check if file exists in current folder
    if (file_exists(ROOT_DIR_APP . "/my-bucket-folder" . $file))
        usingLocalFile(ROOT_DIR_APP . "/my-bucket-folder" . $file); // dont forget to define the ROOT_DIR_APP constant.


} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

function usingLocalFile($file = '')
{

    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (in_array($ext, ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg']))
        header('Content-Type: image/' . $ext);
    else if (in_array($ext, ['pdf', 'json']))
        header('Content-Type: application/' . $ext);
    else
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');

    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');

    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    @readfile($file);

    echo "File Downloaded";
}
```

note: This will not work locally unless you create a (git-ignored) folder to simulate the bucket.

Follow [this](https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/deploy/addon/fs-bucket/#configuring-your-application) good part only in the doc

> *Don’t forget to replace the path of the mounted folder and the fs-bucket host with the targeted folder path (make sure the folder not exists) and your fs-bucket host*